# Theming a views field output using views-view-fields.html.twig

Tags: views, theming, 8

I am trying to customize a views output on a view page to wrap the fields in custom markup. I need to group a set of fields to achieve the desired layout like so:

Example:

```
   <div class="wrapper">
       {{ field.[field_name_1].content }}
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper2">
       {{ field.[field_name_2].content }}
       {{ field.[field_name_3].content }}
       {{ field.[field_name_4].content }}
   </div>
```

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
{% if view.projects_page -%}    
    <div class="project-img columns large-8 medium-12 small-12">
        {{ field.field_project_image.content }}
    </div>
    <div class="description columns large-4 medium-10 small-12">
        {{ field.field_project_header.content }}
        {{ field.field_sub_header.content }}
        {{ field.field_short_project_description.content }}
    </div>
{%- endif %}
```

This doesn't throw any errors but also doesn't seem to work because
 {% if view.projects_page -%} does not target the view in the way I thought it would.

So the question is - How do I detect the view with a conditional so I get the output desired above?

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer documentation for the [working with twig template](https://www.drupal.org/node/2186401). Here you can use conditional twig :

Twig: `{% if field.[field_name].content is not empty %} field.[field_name].content {% endif %}`

Comment: Thank you for the response. The link has been helpful but the code provided still throws errors. Odd because it appears as if it should work. I double checked the field machine name and that is not the problem so I'm gonna keep reading.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is confusing me. Do you really mean views-view-fields.html.twig?
Because you reach the fields like
`{{ fields.[field_name].content }}` and not
`{{ field.[field_name].content }}` and inside the "for" you can test with
`{% if field == fields.[field_name] }}`

**EDIT:**
Ah and try

```
{{ kint(row.[field_name] ,row._entity.get('[field_name]').value) }}
```

Because when you need to check for a value and you have twig in development mode (literally spoken:
`twig.config:
    debug: true`
) you will get the template suggestions in field.content. So when you are checking for the nid it would be
 `{% if row.nid == 900 %} Do someting {% endif %}`
Greeeeetings